# Is inline CSS ok for only one declaration?

Tags: css, inline

I know using inline CSS is generally looked at as bad practice. But if I had a page with an element that only occurred once on the site, (perhaps a dynamically generated table or a form), would it be better to use an inline style if it only had one CSS declaration? It seems almost unnecessary to make an entire style for something that only needs one unique style. Would using an Inline Style be better for these type of situations?

**HTML**

`<div style="padding-left:13px;"></div>`

vs

**HTML/CSS**

`<div class="box"></div>

.box {padding-left:13px;}`

Comment: Better to use class, because if you ever need to modify your code - it will be easier for you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all answers in this realm: It depends...

If you are going for speed then I would recommend strict separation, browsers use highly focused parsing contexts and switching contexts (e.g. HTML to CSS) is non-trivial (or that's what Google and Microsoft have told us). However if you are just going for speed of development, do what works. The ideal situation would use a class, but for prototyping inline styles can be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sometimes elements just need one CSS property. But that doesn't means that it is better to use inline CSS.

One of the advantages of CSS is that you don't need to touch your structure to change something about the site. So, why do you need to change any other file if you can just change it in the CSS?

If any property must set by return of some database or any other source, well, use inline CSS. That's just logic for me. But not inline CSS for *static* properties.